# Draft.js segmented mutability with "." delimiter

Tags: draftjs

Apologies if this is in the documentation, but I've been unable to find it.

With the segmented mutability option, is it possible to have something other than a "space" be the delimiting character? For instance I'm using a "." between words and I'd like a backspace to only erase up to the previous "."

Thanks